# Conditional statements on Panda Dataframes using Lambdas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm getting stuck on a simple point. I'm trying to establish a column within a Panda dataframe, which only pulls up the age for males (0), but for some reason I cannot iterate over the Dataframe (it only repeats the first result, which is 22).

Here is my code:

```
new_tab['menage'] = new_tab.Gender.apply(
        lambda x: new_tab.iloc[:,1] if x==0 
        else 0)

    Original Age    Gender  menage
0   22.0    0   22.0
1   38.0    1   0.0
2   26.0    1   0.0
3   35.0    1   0.0
4   35.0    0   22.0
```

I'm specifically trying to do this for lambda, whilst recognising there are other alternatives available.

I'm sure it's something really straightforward, but being new to coding, is beyond me at present.

Any help would be brilliant.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your expected output, so we can know we understood you correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current operation does not work, because `new_tab.iloc[:,1]` in its entirety is applied *each and every time* the `lambda` is invoked (rather than in an iterative fashion as you'd expect). There are, however, faster options besides `apply`.

**Option 1**
`mask`

```
v = df['Original Age'].mask(df['Gender'].astype(bool)).fillna(0)
v

0    22.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4    35.0
Name: Original Age, dtype: float64

df['menage'] = v
```

---

**Option 2**
`np.where`

```
np.where(df['Gender'], 0, df['Original Age'])

0    22.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4    35.0
Name: Original Age, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3**
The loopy solution with `apply` would involve calling `apply` over the entire `df`, as you need multiple columns accessible in the lambda.

```
df.apply(lambda r: r['Original Age'] if r['Gender'] == 0 else 0, axis=1)

0    22.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4    35.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Coldspeed - thank you very much for your help (along with formatting my original post, as I didn't know how to correctly present my table) - this is genuinely useful, and of real help!

Comment: @Foxtrot82 Can you let me know what your column names are? ["Original Age", "Gender"]? I was confused, I'll fix my answer now. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `assign` and let pandas align the data on index where, the dataframe is filtered using `query` or `boolean indexing`:

```
df.assign(menage = df.query('Gender == 0')['Original Age']).fillna(0)
```

or

```
df.assign(menange = df.loc[df['Gender'] == 0, 'Original Age']).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   Original Age  Gender  menage
0          22.0       0    22.0
1          38.0       1     0.0
2          26.0       1     0.0
3          35.0       1     0.0
4          35.0       0    35.0
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't previously aware of assign, but will look more into that, as it seems quite useful